# Using comparison operators outside of conditionals

Tags: c++, c, comparison-operators

For example

```
int f(int a) {
   ...
   return a > 10;
}
```

is that considered acceptable (not legal, I mean is it ``good code''), or should it always be in a conditional, like this

```
int f(int a) {
   ...
   if (a > 10)
      return 1;
   else
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: Given that the function returns an int, it would be better to use the tertiary operator: return a > 10 ? 1 : 0

Comment: I think Jim means "ternary operator"

Answer (score 37):

It would be acceptable - if your return type was [bool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_datatype#C99).

Answer (score 31):

This is absolutely acceptable! In fact, Joel mentioned this on the latest stackoverflow podcast. He said it was the one thing he's had to show almost every programmer that starts at Fog Creek.

Comment: When I found out that not everyone does it the first way, I was flabbergasted! The first way is so much more readable and concise, whereas the second is harder to understand because a single, simple concept takes four lines rather than one.

Comment: Where I did undergrad, if you did it the second way you lost points on homework. This was in the intro class (pre major).

Comment: Especially if the return type is bool. I cringe when I see something like:

if (a > 1)
    return true;
else
    return false;

Comment: hazzen: You did undergrad at a smart place, then. I went to a community college. I probably forgot more about programming there than I ever learnt.

Answer (score 13):

```
return a > 10 ? 1 : 0;
```

... makes more sense because you're returning an int, not a bool.

Answer (score 6):

The first case is perfectly good, far better than the second, IMHO. As a matter of readability, I personally would do

```
   return  (a > 10);
```

but that is a minor nit, and not one everyone would agree on.

Comment: I don't agree.  It makes it look like you think return is a function being called.

Comment: Only if you put spaces before your parentheses when calling functions, which I don't.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see anything wrong with it. If anything it's more concise and I think most developers with moderate experience would prefer it.

Answer (score 2):

The first is much preferable to me, since it is more concise. (And it avoids multiple returns:)

Answer (score 2):

I'd rather write `bool f(int);` and the first form as bool is the `boolean` type in C++. If I really need to return an `int`, I'd write something like

```
int f(int) {
    ...
    const int res = (i>42) ? 1 : 0;
    return res;
}
```

I'd never understood why people write

```
if (expr == true)
    mybool = true ; 
else 
    mybool = false;
```

instead of the plain

```
mybool = expr;
```

Boolean algebra is a tool that any developer should be able to handle instinctively

*Moreover, I'd rather define a named temporary as some debuggers don't handle function return values very well.*

Comment: I think you meant to return res, not 0.

Comment: The bool type doesn't exist in C, but otherwise, yeah.

Comment: Indeed. Thanks, David.

Regarding bool and C, isn't <stdbool.h> providing a bool type for C99?

Comment: Yeah, kind of. It seems that C99's bool support is the antithesis of deprecation -- still a macro, but reserved in case it's upgraded to full type like in C++. http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/stdbool.h.html says more.

Comment: Surely I can't be the only one that defined BOOL, TRUE and FALSE prior to stdbool.h?

Answer (score 1):

I think its perfectly acceptable, provided that you ensure that you make an extra effort to maintain readability. Like I would make sure that the method name is very unambiguous and you use good variable names.

The second alternative that you provided I think is almost worse because it involves a branch statement and multiple return statements and these things increase the complexity of the method while themselves reducing its readability.

Answer (score 1):

Not only is that syntax 100% acceptable, you should also feel free to use boolean expressions outside of if statements, i.e. `int x = i && ( j || k );` (or returning values like that).

Answer (score 1):

I think part of it has to do with the style and culture of the language. The first example you have written is what would be expected from an experienced C programmer. They would much rather strangle themselves than put in an unnecessary block of statements.

I think it is perfectly acceptable when the language allows it and the usage is part of the paradigm of that language

Answer (score 1):

I just tried three different variants with GCC:

```
int one(int x) { return (x > 42) ? 1 : 0; }
int two(int x) { return x > 42; }
int thr(int x) { if (x > 42) return 1; else return 0; }
```

As soon as you enable some optimization, the generated code for all of them is the same. So you should use the variant that is easiest to read.

Answer (score 0):

I'll typically do the former over the latter.